# Wie übersetzt man "schwerpunktmäßig" ins Englische?

Tags: translation, single-word-request

Wie übersetzt man *schwerpunktmäßig* in Bezug auf Arbeitsfähigkeiten?

Zum Beispiel:

> Herr Schmidt ist schwerpunktmäßig mit den folgenden Tätigkeiten befasst...

Ich hätte gern einziges Wort dafür aber wenn nicht könnte auch umformuliert werden.

---

> Translation (see [here](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/translating-posts-as-a-community-norm)):
>
> How to translate *schwerpunktmäßig* in terms of work skills?
>
> For example:
>
> > Herr Schmidt ist schwerpunktmäßig mit den folgenden Tätigkeiten befasst...
>
> I would like a single word for it, but if there is none it could be reworded.

Comment: Ich will ja nicht meckern aber sollte die Frage nicht eher auf http://english.stackexchange.com/ gestellt werden?

Comment: @sl0815 eher nein: Beide Sprachen sind hier "offiziell" zur Fragestellung und Beantwortung zugelassen und hier ist die Schnittmenge dt/en anteilig wohl wesentlich größer (~100%?!).

Comment: @mbx: ich zitiere mal die FAQ: "GL&U - Stack Exchange is for students having questions about German, expert speakers of German wanting to discuss the finer points of the language and translation questions from any language to German". Diese Frage paßt meiner Meinung nach nicht zu dieser Beschreibung. Aber ich wollte ja nicht meckern und eigentlich isses mir auch egal, ob die Frage nun hier steht oder woanders ;-)

Comment: @sl0815: Wenn's nur danach geht, ja. In en.se müßte man die Frage umformulieren und ggf. übersetzte Alternativen zur Auswahl stellen. In der jetzigen Form ist eine gute Antwort aber wohl hier wahrscheinlicher.

Comment: Fair point, but better to discuss on meta than in comments: http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/136/are-translation-requests-from-german-allowed

Comment: Bei http://english.stackexchange.com/ hab ich selbst Hemmungen nach Übersetzungen von deutsch nach englisch zu fragen. Daher bin ich eher für zulassen. Wo stellt man denn solche Fragen am besten?

Comment: Als Grammatik-Laie dachte ich eigentlich "mäßig"- und "technisch"-Endungen wären sehr ekelig/umgangssprachlich/verpönt?

Comment: @Uwe Ja, es mag sein. Ich bin nicht Muttersprachler (ist auch nicht mein Satz), und solche Tipps sind hilfreich.

Comment: @bernd_k Vermutlich bei http://dict.leo.org/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the English language.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ein Wort, das sich perfekt einsetzen lässt, fällt mir nicht ein.

Eine Möglichkeit wäre to *specialize*:

> Mr. Schmidt specializes in the following areas …

oder wenn das zu stark ist (gut möglich), *focus* oder *emphasis*:

> Mr. Schmidt’s [main] focus is on the following areas …
>
> Mr. Schmidt’s emphasis is on the following areas … (@sarnold says this feels wrong when applied to an individual though)

die nächstliegende wörtliche Übersetzung wäre

> Mr. Schmidt deals mainly with the following areas …

Comment: Ich benütze fast ausschließlich 'focus' und 'emphasizes'. Kam bis jetzt gut an :)

Comment: Ich würde es vielleicht mit "primarily" ansetzen/ergänzen, um den Schwerpunktcharakter zu betonen.

Comment: I wouldn't apply _emphasis_ to an individual; it might be the better word for _groups_ or _ad campaigns_ or _corporations_, but feels wrong for _humans_. (Neat, a new place to give Pekka +1 :)

Comment: @sarnold thanks, I added a caveat! Nice to see you here too. :) Are you a German learner / speaker, or just looking around?

Comment: @Pekka I agree with @sarnold about *emphasis*.  I mean I think it's right to mention it as a possible but the example is infelicitous.

Comment: @Pekka, I'm learning German; I can read e.g. de.wikipedia.com very well :), I can get the gist of conversational written German, but can't speak or write well. (Good enough to travel Germany as a _tourist_, but not yet good enough to get a job. :)

Answer (score 6):

'focus' ist der Ausdruck der Wahl.

> Mr. Smith focuses primarily on the
>   following tasks ...
>   Mr. Smith works
>   with a focus on the following tasks ...

Comment: Genau. Ausserdem ist "schwerpunktmäßig" kein gutes Deutsch. Wenn man umformuliert, erkennt man auch, dass Ihre Antwort gut passt!

Answer (score 2):

> Herr Schmidt ist schwerpunktmäßig mit den folgenden Tätigkeiten befasst...

Meine erste Antwort wäre auch 'mainly':

> Mr. Schmidt is mainly sitting around, doing nothing.

aber gelegentlich bin ich auch den Schlüsseltätigkeiten begegnet:

> The key activities of Mr. Schmidt are eating, sleeping and drinking.